# Suppress abbreviated citation in list of references when using nocite

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

Dear TeX Exchange users,

I'm converting a MS Word document to LaTeX and am using `\nocite{*}` to include a bibliography of references that are not cited within the .tex document using `\cite`, rather are just plain text. However, I'd like to suppress the appearance of the abbreviated citation before each reference in the list (i.e. if I use the 'plain' bibliography style, there is a [1] before the first reference etc..).

I can provide a MWE if my explanation is unclear, thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Do you have several bibliographies in your document or just one? If more than one bibliography is used, then it would be a good idea to edit your question and add a minimal, complete version of your document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: I'm only using a single bibliography file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to use a style not labeling the bibliographical items. If, for some reason, you want to keep the `plain` style, then you can add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\setlength\labelsep{0pt}}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother
```

The `\renewcommand` line suppresses the label used in the document and the line beginning with `\AtBeginEnvironment` simply suppresses the small remaining indentation of the items given by `\labelsep`.

Comment: @Thraupidae: You're welcome!